Lebesgue outer measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in terms of a grid of $h$-squares
For a set $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, the Lebesgue outer measure of $D$ is defined by
$$\lambda^\ast(D)=\inf\bigg\{\sum_i\lambda(I_i)\mid D\subseteq\bigcup_iI_i\bigg\},$$
where $\{I_i\}$ is a sequence of closed rectangles, and $\lambda(I_i)$ is the area of $I_i$. Now, divide $\mathbb{R}^2$ into a grid of squares with edge length $h$ (called $h$-squares) by the lines $x=0,\pm h,\pm2h,\pm3h,\cdots$ and $y=0,\pm h, \pm2h, \pm3h,\cdots$ Let $D_h$ be the set of $h$-squares intersecting $D$, and
$$A(D,h)=\sum_{\sigma\in D_h}h^2.$$
If $D$ is compact, then it can be covered by finitely many closed rectangles, the sum of whose areas is arbitrarily close to $\lambda^\ast(D)$, and each rectangle can be approximated by $h$-squares, so
\begin{equation}
\lambda^\ast(D)=\lim_{h\to0^+}A(D,h).\tag{$\ast$}\label{this}
\end{equation}
My question is whether \eqref{this} holds even when $D$ is not compact. To make things simpler, let us assume that $D$ is bounded.

You didn't define $\sigma$. If that sum is counting how many squares intersect your set, you could write it as $A(D,h)=h^2\cdot |D_h|$?

You might find something useful in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_cubes. Dyadic cubes are a generalization of your idea

@Zima $\sigma$ is an element of $D_h$. Yes, you could write $A(D,h)=h^2\cdot|D_h|$.

No, it does not hold. For example, consider the set
$$D=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}\mid0\leq x\leq 1,\ 0\leq y\leq 1\big\}.$$
$\lambda^\ast(D)=0$, but $A(D,h)=1$ for all $h>0$, so $\lim_{h\to0^+}A(D,h)=1$.
